# How to reset the slider value based on checkbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, rangeslider

I have a range slier & I am trying to reset it's value to default if a checkbox is clicked.
Can anyone tell how to do this?

This is what I tried:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="range" id="myRange" max="10000" min="60">
<input type="checkbox" id="lala" onclick="myFunction()"> checkme
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function myFunction()
{
   document.getElementById('myRange').value=60;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltwtjt48/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to call undefined function, I´ve edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3kqyaaup/2/ (move JS into `<head>`) and it works.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById('myRange').value=60;
}
</script>

<input type="range" id="myRange" max="10000" min="60">
<input type="checkbox" id="lala" onclick="myFunction()"> checkme
```

Comment: What was wrong with my fiddle?? Both the fiddles looks like twins. @panther

Comment: @BeingJudas check "Frameworks & Extensions" (top left hand corner), bottom drop-down has been changed from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`...

Comment: So...there was nothin' wrong with my code. jsFiddle acted like an asshole. Thanks ya'.